# Applying Solve to a list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Given a list of functions

```
flist = {f[x, y], g[x, y], h[x, y], ...};
```

I wish to some way apply Solve to flist to obtain

```
Solve[f[x, y] == g[x, y] == h[x, y] == ..., {x, y}]
```

Where there may be any number of functions in `flist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `Head` of your list from `List` to `Equal` using `Apply`:

```
Equal @@ flist
(* Out: f[x, y] == g[x, y] == h[x, y] *)
```

You can then use this within `Solve`:

```
Solve[Equal@@flist, {x, y}]
```